# Как заблокировать несколько разных кнопок в рамках одной функции? (JS/jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть несколько кнопок с id "btn-pay-.." (ниже привожу пример только одной кнопки). При выполнение скрипта, кнопка блокируется, однако функция не универсальная (приходится копировать ее много раз, чтобы блокировать разные кнопки). Подскажите, как рефакторить код, чтобы можно было блокировать разные кнопки в рамках одной функции (не привязываться к ID)?

```js
function DisableBtn4() {
    $(this).on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
        $("#btn-pay-4").prop("disabled", true);
    });
};
```

```html
  <button class="btn btn-primary mt-4 ml-4" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#finish_transfer_4" aria-expanded="false"
                        aria-controls="collapseExample" id="btn-pay-4" onclick="DisableBtn4();">Перевести 25 000 ₽</button>
```

Comment: привязаться не к `id`, а к классу

Answer (score 0):

Я бы переработал функцию так:

```
var selectorsArray = {'#btn-pay-4'};
 function DisableBtns(selectorsArray) {
    $(this).on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
        selectorsArray.each(function(i, elem){
            $(elem).prop("disabled", true);
        });
    });
};
```

В таком случае вы используете эту функцию один раз и заблокируете все нужные вам кнопки